# Intellij IDEA 15 how to open multiple Windows, each window is independent

Tags: intellij-idea

There are currently two projects. I want to open a separate window for each item.

How to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open menu "File" --> "Settings..." . Insert "window" in the search text field and take a look at the options:

[image]

Comment: OS X with Intellij 2019.2: This option is found in Preferences -> System Settings